# Groovy: passing PermSize to groovy compiler from IntellijIdea

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy, groovyc

I have big grails project (five modules + 2 custom no pre-compiled plugins).

At first – compilation was failed with out of memory in javac. I added as params:

```
-J-Xmx1024m  -J-Xms512m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

[image: -J-Xmx1024m -J-Xms512m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m]

great, first OOM – fixed.

At second – I have OOM in groovy compiler. How to pass memory params from Idea to groovyc? Also my application should work in NOT forking mode

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the groovyc memory directly.
You should set/increase your memory settings directly in the IntelliJ settings.
The documentation can be found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/increasing-memory-heap.html

In general, in your IntelliJ installation's bin folder, there will be 2 files of interest: **idea.exe.vmoptions** and **idea64.exe.vmoptions**. You would adjust the settings for the file that matches the idea.exe or idea64.exe you use to launch IntelliJ

Within the file, you can adjust your heap memory for IntelliJ as a whole. My guess is you are running out of perm gen space and should increase your MaxPermGenSize. The settings would looks similar to this (I have 16gb memory on my PC):

```
-Xms750m
-Xmx2g
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
```